# Can't add type to dictionary

Tags: c#, generics

The code is somewhat contrived of course, but here goes. My pretty straight forward dictionary:

```
public class ValidatorRepository // BusinessRuleValidator implements IBusinessRuleValidator
{
    public static Dictionary<ValidationAttribute, BusinessRuleValidator> Repo 
       = new Dictionary<ValidationAttribute, BusinessRuleValidator>();        
}
```

Some custom attribute:

```
public class MySuperAttribute : ValidationAttribute
```

Some validator:

```
public class MySuperValidator : BusinessRuleValidator
```

However:

```
  ValidatorRepository.Repo.Add(MySuperAttribute, typeof(MySuperValidator));
```

Only works for the second object, the first one complains:

> MySuperAttribute' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tried putting typeof() around it to no success. Now it's been a hellish long day and I'm probably just missing something utterly stupod, but please help. I really can't see what's wrong :(

Comment: What's this? `ValidatorRepository.Repo.Add(MySuperAttribute, typeof(MySuperValidator));` Dictionary should contain actual objects/instances and not types.

Comment: Your dictionary is expecting instances of your classes, not their types which would be the `Type` class anyway.

Comment: So `ValidationAttribute` is a type. It's the name of a class. You defined a class by that name, or somebody did. That means that your Dictionary wants *an object of that type* for a key when you add a value to the dictionary. That is to say, an *instance* of that type. Is an instance of `Type` an instance of `ValidationAttribute`? No. It's a different type. Is the *name* of a type an instance of that type, or of anything? No. It wants an instance of `ValidationAttribute`. An object of that type.

Comment: Thanks guys, 2 15 hour days with 3 hours of sleep = this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary<ValidationAttribute, BusinessRuleValidator>`

It's expecting an instance of `ValidationAttribute` as the key, and an instance of `BusinessRuleValidator` as the value.

Comment: the jjoys of making way too long days